# Question about making a custom 'formula'

Tags: integer-programming, floating-point

I am working on some program for myself, and I am stuck on one thing, which I am not sure how to make exactly, I do know how to calculate it manually on paper, but I don't know any kind of formula or algorithm to help me make a program do it.

So, basically, this is what I'm trying to do.

I have 3 digits (floating point numbers). Examples: 1.25, 5.20, 9.00, 18.00, 2.95, 2.05 etc.

Now, I want to give a real example of what I'm doing manually:

I have 3 digits as we said, so example this:

2.35 3.15 2.45

And, I do multiplication of each number with 'specific' number, so I can check whether the number after multiplication is lower than the total sum of the multiplicands.

Example:

2.35 * 1.03 = 2.4205

3.15 * 0.97 = 3.0555

2.45 * 1 = 2.45

In this case, my program should give a warning that the 3 numbers do not meet the requirements, because:

1.03 + 0.97 + 1 = 3, and 2.4205 < 3, and also 2.45 < 3, so only 2nd one meets the condition. (all should meet the condition to be correct)

Here is an example, where it is correct:

The 3 numbers are: 1.25, 9.00 and 13.0

1.25 * 5.2 = 6.5

9.00 * 0.8 = 7.2

13.0 * 0.5 = 6.5

So, it is correct because, all of the results after multiplication are either bigger or equal to the total sum of all multiplicands. In this case, 5.2 + 0.8 + 0.5 = 6.5. And that means, 6.5 >= 6.5, 7.2 >= 6.5, 6.5 >= 6.5.

So, I was wondering, is there any other way I could use or some algorithm that I could use in my program to do this calculation? I have to do lots of calculations daily, so I want to make my job easier with a program.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does the multiplicands come from?

Comment: @Darksonn I manually think of them, I choose the lowest possible numbers, but it can be done with any numbers, doesn't have to be that small, it just makes it easier for me manually.

Comment: So you have two sets of numbers and need to check if those sets together match that $a_i \times b_i>\sum b_n$ am I right?

Comment: Two sets of numbers? What do you exactly mean by that? I want to check if all the results after multiplication are either bigger or equal than the total sum of all the multiplicands. (The numbers in the first column are not random ones, I get them from a source, the numbers in the second column are the multiplicands, whose sum can't exceed any of the results after multiplication (which is the third column).)

Comment: So would a solution be, given the numbers from the first column, output numbers for the second column that matches?

Comment: Hm.. you mean in last example, given the numbers 1.25, 9.00 and 13.0, to output the numbers 5.2, 0.8 and 0.5 (or numbers even closer?)? But how do we know whether the sum of them doesn't exceed any of the results after multiplication?

Comment: The program that outputs those numbers could make sure that those numbers it outputs do, in fact, not exceed. Also are there ever more than 3 numbers?

Comment: No, there are ALWAYS 3 numbers. No more, no less.

Comment: It seemd that lett ing all multiplicatirs be zero always works: $0\ge 0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen A little flaw, I'd say, but 0 is not allowed in my case unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3$ be positive  real numbers. We want to find positve real numbers  $b_1, b_2, b_3$ such that $a_ib_i\ge b_1+b_2+b_3$ for $i=1,2,3$.
We may multiply all $b_i$ with a positive constant without any changes to the conditions, hence assume wlog. that $b_1+b_2+b_3=1$.
Then we obtain the condition $b_i\ge \frac1{a_i}$. This is compatible with $b_1+b_2+b_3=1$ if and only if $\frac1{a_1}+\frac1{a_2}+\frac1{a_3}\le 1$. Indeed, if $\frac1{a_1}+\frac1{a_2}+\frac1{a_3}\le 1$, we can let $b_1=\frac1{a_1}$, $b_2=\frac1{a_2}$, $b_3=1-b_1-b_2$ and are done.

**Example:** with $a_1 = 1.25$, $a_2= 9$, $a_3= 13$, we have $\frac1{a_1}+\frac1{a_2}+\frac1{a_3}\approx 0.988<1$, so all is fine and we have a decent amount of "free space". We can let $b_1=\frac1{a_1}=0.8$, and $b_2=0.12$ (which is a generous round-up of $\frac1{a_2}=0.1111\ldots$) and $b_3=1-b_1-b_2=0.08$ (which, luckily, is greater than $\frac1{a_3}=0.076923\ldots$). Then $b_1+b_2+b_3=1$, $a_1b_1=1\ge 1$, $a_2b_2= 1.08\ge 1$, $a_3b_3=1.04\ge 1$.

Comment: Do you mind showing a real example with numbers from my first post? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user167641 The number 1.25 will be multiplied by 1/1.25=0.8, the second number 9 will be multiplied by 1/9=0.11 the third number will be multiplied with 1-0.8-0.11=0.09

Comment: OP said something about making a program in his post, here's a program that calculates numbers using the rules in this answer [source](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=P6ad1j7u), it can be compiled with `g++ numbers.c -o numbers.exe`

Comment: @Darksonn I assumed the OP migh be able to do the transefer from my formulas to his programming situation just as easily as from your C code to code in whatever his programming languge may be.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks a lot for your time, to both of you! I appreciate it.